# How to programmatically edit users in a local IBM Notes group?

Tags: c#, lotus-notes

I am using IBM Notes 9. In my Inbox I click on the little three-bars icon next to my name, and then click on "Switch to Mail Contacts." Then the Contacts window opens up and I select "Groups" on the left-hand sidebar. This gives me my list of groups. One of these group lists is called "WebDesignCommittee" and it has a list of Notes users. I want to be able to edit this list from a C# script using the IBM Notes domino interop. Is this possible. Where is this WebDesignCommittee group being stored? On our Notes server or in my local Notes directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's definitely possible, but I've got to be honest about this: If I were responsible for maintaining your server, I would not give anything more than Reader rights to someone who doesn't even know where groups live, especially if they're talking about trying to write code to modify them!

Anyhow, if you created the group for your own use, then it is going to be in your local names.nsf database and you won't have to worry about what rights you've been given.  If you didn't create it, and it is a shared group that anyone can use, then it is in names.nsf on your server - then you may or may not have the Author or Editor rights that are required to edit it.

Comment: the way he decribes it, he opens the group from his personal mailfile. It is synced there from local addressbook with replicator option "synchronize contacts"...